# Поиск подстроки без использования регулярных выражений

Tags: c++, строки

> Задание: Из строки, состоящей из букв, цифр, запятых, точек, знаков + и – , выделить подстроку, задающую вещественное число с фиксированной точкой. **Не используя Regex.**

Проблема заключается в том, что при вводе строки "asd.qrg+-12.15" не выводит число. Может подскажите как сделать так, чтобы если возле первой точки буквы, то искало следующую и т.д.?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include<string> 
using namespace std;
int main(int args, double, char * argv[]) {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int c, o, t, u, v, n = 0;
int f = 0;
int b = 0;
int m = 0;
o = 0;
u = 0;
t = 0;
string sr; 
cout << "Введите строку" << endl;
getline(cin, sr); 
for (int i = 0; i < sr.length(); i++) {
    if (sr[i] == '.') { 
        if (!(isdigit(sr[i + 1])) || !(isdigit(sr[i - 1]))) { 
            t = 1;
            break;
        }
        else {
            for (v = i - 1; v > 0; v--) { 
                if (isdigit(sr[v])) {
                    b = v;
                }
                else {
                    if (sr[v] == '-') {
                        b = v;
                        break;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
            }
            for (f = b; f < sr.length(); f++) {
                if (sr[f] == '.') {
                    break;
                }
                if (sr[f] == '-') {
                    continue;
                }
                o++;
            }
        }
        f = 0;
        for (int n = i + 1; n < sr.length(); n++) {
            if (isdigit(sr[n])) {
                m = n;  
            }
            else break;
        }
        for (f = m; f > 0; f--) {  
            if (sr[f] == '.') {
                break;
            }
            u++;
        }
    }
}
if (o == u) {
    c = 0;
}
else {
    c = 1;
}
if (c == 0 && t == 0) {
    cout << "Число = ";
    for (int i = b; i <= m; i++) {
        cout << sr[i];
    }
}
else {
    cout << "такого числа нет";
}
cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для таких целей существует regex.

Comment: @LLENN Задание так же заключается в том, чтобы не использовать regex

Comment: Любопытно, зачем такие идиотские задания? мышление развивать? Примерно тоже как рассыпать спички и по одной собирать, вместо пылесоса :)

Comment: @MBo Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Нашёл более лёгкий способ избежать данную проблему. Во втором по счёту if,где происходит проверка, нужно было убрать строку "t=1;" и заменить break на continue.

Comment: У вас, кстати, `isdigit` неправильно используется. Нужно вот так: `isdigit((unsigned char)sr[i + 1])`. [Пруф](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте разбор строки [конечным автоматом](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B), который обрабатывает символы по порядку.

Для каждого возможного состояния нужно предусмотреть набор переходов в другие состояния (или в это же) в зависимости от очередного символа

Таким образом, задаётся начальное состояние, набор возможных символов (алфавит), строится таблица переходов

Некий образец (для этой задачи не вполне подходит):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Крнечно не лучший код, но работаюший:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//функтор рассматривает одну точку или одну запятую как часть числа
struct Nnumber {
    static int k;
    bool operator ()(char ch) {
        if (ch == '.' || ch == ',') {
            ++k;
            return k > 1;
        }
        return !isdigit(ch);
    }
};
int Nnumber::k = 0;

int main()
{        
    string s = "asd.qrg+-12.1,5 ....";
    size_t sz = s.length(), i = 0;
    for (; i < sz; ++i)
        if (isdigit(s[i]))
            break;
    if (i) {
        --i;
        if (s[i] == '.')
            --i;
    }
    char c = (s[i] == '-')  ? s[i] : 0 ;
    s = s.substr(i);
    string::iterator  p = std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), Nnumber());
    s.erase(p,  s.end());
    if(c == '-')
        s.insert(s.begin(), c);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл более лёгкий способ избежать данную проблему.В  if,где происходит проверка, нужно было убрать строку "t=1;" и заменить break на continue.

```
    //было
    if (!(isdigit(sr[i + 1])) || !(isdigit(sr[i - 1]))) { 
        t = 1; 
        break;
    }
    //стало
    if (!(isdigit(sr[i + 1])) || !(isdigit(sr[i - 1]))) { 
        continue;
    }
```